# QA Results/Custom Text in CloudBees Jenkins Pipeline Stage View?

Tags: cloudbees, jenkins-pipeline

We're building out builds using the Pipeline Plugin, and using the CloudBees Stage View.

I'm wondering if it's possible to change the text inside of the box for each stage, while that stage is running.  Right now it only displays the amount of time it's been running.  I'd be interested to display some testing results instead ("12 of 20 test passed", for example).

Or, is there a better way to display such test results on the Stage View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not currently. [JENKINS-26522](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26522) tracks essentially this request.